# Randomizing a list of chars in a string, C#

Tags: c#, string, random, char

I've been playing around / researching ways to randomize the order of chars in a string. I frankly just don't understand how to do it. I've searched through the C# documentation and a handful of websites. I found one particular way of randomizing the order of chars in a string but I don't understand how it works. I've also read that the Random class isn't truly random, which would explain why the results are so similar.

How exactly does the current method I'm using function (especially the OrderBy() method).
Is there a better way to do this?

Current code

```
string baseList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        Random random = new Random();
        string[] randLists = new string[baseList.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < baseList.Length; i++)
        {
            randLists[i] = new string(baseList.ToCharArray().OrderBy(s => (random.Next(2) % 2) == 0).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(randLists[i]);
        }
        Console.Read();
```

This is my attempt at randomizing but it doesn't function at all:

```
*string bL = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            string[] rL = new string[bL.Length];
            Random randomizer = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < bL.Length; i++)
            {
                rL = new string(bL.ToCharArray().OrderBy(c => (randomizer.Next(0, 25)).ToString()));
            }*
```

Thanks in advance for any assistance. I'll continue researching in the meantime.

Comment: rather than randomizing on a number between 0 and 25, which has a rather high probability of colliding, instead order on just `Next()` (without arguments) to get a number in the full range of `int32`.  It will have a much lower chance of colliding.  Since it's a stable sort, the higher the probability of collision the more the starting order biases the result.  And your first method, with a random generator only choosing between two numbers, has a much higher rate of collision, and so has an even greater bias towards the original order.

Comment: Oh, and the `ToCharArray` call isn't needed; `string` already implements `IEnumerable<char>`, and so you can call `OrderBy` on it.

Comment: @Servy Thanks Servy. Both pieces of advice helped.

Answer (score 5):

Although the code that you found is short, it does not make a nicely distributed shuffle of the original string: the randomizer is likely to give you the same numbers in the process of generating a shuffle, increasing a probability that the corresponding characters would remain in the same order relative to each other as in your original string.

One solution to this problem is using [*Fisher–Yates shuffle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). It is easy to implement (you need to stay away from [common implementation errors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle#Implementation_errors), though).

Since `string` is immutable, you would need to shuffle an array of characters, and then make a `string` from it.

Comment: `OrderBy` actually ensures that the selector is run exactly once per item in the sequence, so no, it *cannot* result in generating two different numbers for the same string, so it is properly random.  It's less efficient, but not incorrect, with the exception of the fact that, as I said in an earlier comment, his current random number is rather likely to collide, as opposed to just calling `Next()`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to the suggestion of the Fisher-Yates shuffle, here's a code sample, just ignore the test assertion, just trying to debug and make sure it's random enough.

```
[TestMethod]
        public void RandomizeText()
        {
            string baseList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
            char[] result = baseList.ToCharArray();
            Shuffle<char>(result);
            var final = string.Join("", result);
            final.Should().NotMatch(baseList);

        }
    public void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
    {
        var random = new Random();
        for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
            {
                // Pick random element to swap.
                int j = random.Next(i); // 0 <= j <= i-1
                // Swap.
                T tmp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[i - 1];
                array[i - 1] = tmp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll definitely look into it more, but for now Servy's advice seems sufficient for my little program. I'm still learning the fundamentals of programming as well as the specifics of C# so I'm just trying to keep it as simple as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another example...

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string baseList = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
        Console.WriteLine(baseList);
        string shuffled = Shuffle(baseList);
        Console.WriteLine(shuffled);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static Random R = new Random();

    static string Shuffle(string list)
    {
        int index;
        List<char> chars = new List<char>(list);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (chars.Count > 0)
        {
            index = R.Next(chars.Count);
            sb.Append(chars[index]);
            chars.RemoveAt(index);
        }
        return sb.ToString();
    }
```